# Precalculus math question natural logs

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I go about expanding this expression using the law of logs?

$$\ln\sqrt{\frac{a^3b}{c^4}}$$

Comment: what are YOUR IDEAS?

Comment: i was thinking by multyplying the denominator to get rid off the fraction?

Comment: well, you don't *exactly* multiply to get rid of a fraction when it's inside a log.  But if you keep in mind that log(a/b) = log a - log b and you're on your way.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming $a.b,c\in\mathbb{R^+}$:

Using the follwing rules:

1) $\ln\left(a^b\right)=b\ln(a)$;

2) $\ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=\ln(a)-\ln(b)$

$$\ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{a^3b}{c^4}}\right)=\ln\left(\left(\frac{a^3b}{c^4}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{a^3b}{c^4}\right)}{2}=\frac{\ln(a^3b)-\ln(c^4)}{2}=$$
$$\frac{\ln(a^3b)-4\ln(c)}{2}=\frac{3\ln(a)+\ln(b)-4\ln(c)}{2}$$

Comment: i think you are wrong:$\ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=\ln(a)-\ln(b)$ holds only for $a,b>0$

Comment: if i had wrote such a nonsense i would get $-\infty$ by Daniel Fisher

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I've edited my answer, I said $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R^+}$.

Answer (score 1):

What properties of logarithms allow you to deal with exponents, products, and quotients? How are they useful in the expression with which you are working?

Answer (score 1):

Use the properties of logarithms.

You can take out the square root, as log($a^b$)$=b$log($a$).

Then, use the facts that

log($a$)$+$log($b$)$=$log($ab$) and

log($a$)$-$log($b$)$=$log($\frac{a}{b}$)

to further expand.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$\sqrt{\frac{a^3b}{c^4}}=\frac{a^{3/2}b^{1/2}}{c^2}=a^{3/2}b^{1/2}c^{-2}.$$
Thus,
$$\begin{align}
\ln\sqrt{\frac{a^3b}{c^4}}&=\ln(a^{3/2}b^{1/2}c^{-2})\\
\\\quad
&=\ln(a^{3/2})+\ln(b^{1/2})+\ln(c^{-2})\tag{$\ln(xy)=\ln x+\ln y$}\\\\\quad
&=\frac{3}{2}\ln a+\frac{1}{2}\ln b-2\ln c\tag{$\ln x^y=y\ln x$}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Each of the rules of exponents has a coresponding rule of logarithms.

1) $b^mb^n = b^{n+m}$ <==> $\log(xy) = \log x + \log y$

1') $b^m/b^n = b^{m - n}$ <==> $\log(x/y) = \log x - \log y$

2) $(b^m)^n = b^m*n$ <==> $\log x^n = n \log x$.

2') $\sqrt[m] b = b^{1/m}$ <==> $ \log \sqrt[m]x = \frac 1 m \log x$.

These rules are obvious if you consider: $b^m = x \iff \log_b x = m$ so they all follow.

So apply the rules to $\ln\sqrt{\frac{a^3b}{c^4}}$ one after another. First the square root rule:

$\ln\sqrt{\frac{a^3b}{c^4}} = \ln {\frac{a^3b}{c^4}}^{1/2} = \frac 1 2 \ln\frac{a^3b}{c^4}$

Then the division:

$ \frac 1 2 \ln\frac{a^3b}{c^4} =  \frac 1 2[\ln {a^3b} - \ln c^4]$

and so on.

.... Or you could note

$\ln\sqrt{\frac{a^3b}{c^4}} =  \ln {\frac{|a| \sqrt {|ab|}}{c^2}}  $ and apply the rules.  The result will be the same.